# Como tratar um feed com extensão .rss

Tags: php, xml

Recebo um XML através de uma URL de feed com extensão .RSS. Estou tentando efetuar a leitura do XML e não obtive êxito. Tentei das seguintes maneiras:

```
$url = 'http://www.feedaqui.com.br/recent.rss';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$url = 'http://www.feedaqui.com.br/recent.rss';
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($url));
```

Gerando o erro:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity
```

Comment: Qual o erro que dá?

Comment: Editei e adicionei o erro.

Comment: No seu php.ini, altere a configuração allow_url_fopen para on ou utilize curl.

Comment: Utilizei o cURL e a dica do gist 5405671 do betweenbrain
https://gist.github.com/betweenbrain/5405671

Comment: Se funcionar, adicione uma resposta e valide-a depois de dois dias.

Comment: A extensão na nomenclatura do arquivo/url não influencia em nada. O importante é o content-type e o conteúdo em si. Exemplo, a URL pode ser http://.../feed.exe e se o .exe retornar um content-type do tipo texto, então será tratado como texto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, Array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => 'http://www.feedaqui.com.br/recent.rss';
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'spider',
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => 'UTF-8'
));

$data = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```